# DataTable.AsEnumerable().Distinct() doesn't work because of primary key column

Tags: .net, linq, ado.net, datatable, linq-to-dataset

I want to remove duplicates from my `DataTable` so I'm using `DataTable.AsEnumerable().Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default)` but it doesn't do what I need. I think because each duplicate row has it's unique primary key column.

How can I do what I need? Write my own `DataRowComparer`? I don't want - because the default must works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DistinctBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) from the [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) project. Basically you specify a projection from a data row to the columns you're interested in, and it will use that. For example:

```
var rows = DataTable.AsEnumerable()
                    .DistinctBy(row => new { Name = row["Name"],
                                             Age = row["Age"] });
```

When you say "the default must work" that's basically not going to happen if you have a normal primary key column. Two rows with the different primary key values *aren't* duplicates of each other, because they differ in that data.

Another option would be to project to data rows *without* that primary key column, and then use the normal `Distinct` method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the defaultview.rowfilter to launch a query that group by unique columns, and SELECT the MIN (or MAX) RowId as the row to keep.

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows) question for more info abour the query.